# GWT MAP 3.8 (Google API) - Is onResize() needed to hide the "grey background"?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

My problem:

- I display a map inside a popup and I have unloaded tiles (grey background).
- If I zoom out or in, then the map will fill the entire space (no grey background anymore).

My question:

- Have you any idea about my problem (Should I need to resize to hide the "grey background") ?
- I do not know if I should call onResize() inside the Runnable callback (code is above) or not ?

Thanks you,

My actual code: (I am using the javaxLoaderAPI)

// ENTRY POINT

> ```
>   GoogleMap map;
>   @UiField LayoutPanel gmap;
>
>   public void AjaxLoader_MAP() {
>
>           AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
>
>           options.setOtherParms("key=***&sensor=false&language=es");
>
>           Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
>              public void run() {
>                 gmap.onResize();         // Should I call onResize() here  ? 
>                 map = GoogleMap.create(gmap.getElement());    
>              };
>           }
> ```

> ```
>           AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

May be related to the following post - [GWT Google Map Api V3 - broken when changing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799547/gwt-google-map-api-v3-broken-when-changing-it)

I just posted an answer to that unanswered post as well.  I believe it answers and sheds insight on this one as well.

I know this is an old post, but let me know if helps!

Answer (score 0):

When calling mapWidget.triggerResize(), it's important to call it with some delay (Timer.schedule()) so that all the widget have been reset and then the map is resized.

This is how I trigger it:

```
@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();
    Timer timer = new Timer() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            triggerResize();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(100);
}
```

Without timer, I was still getting grey tiles. Hope someone still finds it useful.