# GWT Google Map Api V3 - broken when changing it

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, gwt-2.5

It is working fine for me for the first time it is rendered.
But, If I change anything over the map or recreate it, its broken.

Here is the screen shot for how it looks.
[image: Here]

Here is a screen shot after I changed the results per page value.
[image: Here]

This is my code.

```
@UiField DivElement mapPanel;

private GoogleMap googleMap;

public void loadAllMarkers(final List<LatLng> markers)
{
    if(!markers.isEmpty())
    {
        final MapOptions options = MapOptions.create();
        options.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

        googleMap = GoogleMap.create(mapPanel, options);

        final LatLngBounds latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.create();

        for(LatLng latLng : markers)
        {
        final MarkerOptions markerOptions = MarkerOptions.create();

        markerOptions.setPosition(latLng);
        markerOptions.setMap(googleMap);

        final Marker marker = Marker.create(markerOptions);
        latLngBounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

        }

        googleMap.setCenter(latLngBounds.getCenter());
        googleMap.fitBounds(latLngBounds);

    }
}
```

I am calling the loadAllMarkers() method whenever new results needs to be loaded.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to come from the following (which I pulled from a Google+ Community - [GWT Maps V3 API](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/105780740892495987648)):

> Brandon DonnelsonMar 5, 2013
>
> I've had this happen and forgotten why it is, but
>   mapwidget.triggerResize() will reset the tiles. This seems to happen
>   when the onAttach occurs and animation exists meaning that the div
>   started smaller and increases in side, but the map has already
>   attached. At the end of the animation, the map doesn't auto resize.
>   I'v been meaning to investigate auto resize but I haven't had time to
>   attack it yet.

In your case, you would call googleMap.triggerResize() after you finish your changes.  this solved my problem when I had the exact same issue.  I know it's a little late, but I hope it helps!

Another answer there was to extend the Map widget with the following:

```
   @Override
protected void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();
    Timer timer = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            resize();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(5);
}

/*
 * This method is called to fix the Map loading issue when opening
 * multiple instances of maps in different tabs
 * Triggers a resize event to be consumed by google api in order to resize view
 * after attach.
 *
 */
public void resize() {
    LatLng center = this.getCenter();
    MapHandlerRegistration.trigger(this, MapEventType.RESIZE);        
    this.setCenter(center);
}
```